# Creating grunt tasks for compiling coffeescript files recursively inside directories and subdirectories

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-coffee

I am trying to create a grunt task to compile coffeescript code spread across multiple files to .js files of the same name. I have the grunt coffeescript plugin and I am looking to use the "glob_to_multiple" spec that is given on this page:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-coffee.

```
 glob_to_multiple: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    cwd: 'path/to',
    src: ['*.coffee'],
    dest: 'path/to/dest/',
    ext: '.js'
  },
```

However, this grunt task does not compile .coffee files to .js files of corresponding names - for all .coffee files in a directory and its sub directories. I've been tweaking this config, for a while but I can't get it to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern `*.coffee` will only match files that end with `.coffee` in the `cwd` folder. The pattern `**/*.coffee` will match all files that end with `.coffee` recursively in all sub folders of `cwd` and the `cwd` itself.

Try the following config:

```
glob_to_multiple: {
  expand: true,
  flatten: true,
  cwd: 'path/to',
  src: ['**/*.coffee'],
  dest: 'path/to/dest/',
  ext: '.js'
},
```

Also remove `flatten: true` if you want it to recreate the folder structure in `path/to/dest/` instead of compiling all files to the single folder.

Comment: That part worked. But it creates all the .js files in one directory instead of creating them in the same directory as the source .coffee file. And if there are more than one files with the same name ( Eg. `<filename>.coffee`), then it creates a common js file for both in the output directory called `<filename>.js` and concatenates the .coffee files with the common name into one file in the destination directory named `<filename>.src.js`. All I want is for one .js file to produced for each .coffee file

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer provided by Kyle does the exact opposite of what you want to achieve!

To make it work like you want to, just set `dest: path/to`. Make sure to set `flatten: false` flag.

With the below example you can make it work

```
coffee: {
  glob_to_multiple: {
      expand: true,
      flatten: false,
      cwd: '',
      src: ['server/api/**/*.coffee', 'client/app/**/*.coffee'],
      dest: '',
      ext: '.js',
      extDot: 'last'
  }
}
```

In the `src:[]` array you can put in whatever root/subdirs you want to be crawled.  You could also `cwd: ''` and `dest: ''` to crawl your whole project including node_modules directory, just as a proof of concept. All js files will get created at the exact same spot where their corresponding coffee origins are located. The `extDot: 'last'` makes sure that files like `myUnitTest.spec.coffee` will get processed properly as well.